# How to implement async calls to db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, async-await

I need help friends!
I need to write function for get request in my REST API.
In this function I need to get all playlists by branchId, and get for each playlist files by playlistId, and send array of objects with properties [{playlist, files}, {playlist, files}, {playlist, files}].

I think my function need to be async.
I try it, but I have some problems when I want to get files for each playlist.

```
exports.findBranchePlaylists = async  function(req, res) {
    let data = [];
    let playlists = await Playlist.find({branch_id: req.params.branchId});
    playlists.forEach(async (playlist) => {
        let files = await File.find({playlistId: playlist._id });
        data.push({playlist, files});
    })
    res.send(playlists);
};
```

I know that it is wrong code, I want to show you, what I want to do. 
this code send me only this - [].

Comment: forEach does not supports async/await syntax. Place your code inside a FOR loop and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with your code is that forEach loop does not suppports await syntax (as forEach is NOT async). You can change the forEach to be a classic FOR loop.
Me personally I would do it like this (so 1 call will give me the data for all the ids):

`exports.findBranchePlaylists = async  function(req, res) {
    let data = [];
    let playlists = await Playlist.find({branch_id: req.params.branchId});
    let files = await File.find({'playlistId': {$in: playlists.map( ele => ele._id) });
    res.send(files);
};`

Comment: It returns me this []

Comment: I change for each to for and it work, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be async, you can make use of promise or callback function

```
exports.findBranchePlaylists = function(req, res) {
Playlist.find({branch_id: req.params.branchId})
        .then(result => {
    return result.map(plylist => {
         File.find({playlistId: playlist._id })
              .then(result => { return {playlist, result} })
    })
}).then( result => res.send(result))
};
```

or you can use for loop with async/await as forEach is not supported with async/await.

Comment: It doesn't work, it give me an array of nulls

Comment: There might be typo in variable names, Have a better look at it. Found one typo and updated the answer, updated the answer.

Comment: yeah, i see that typeos but it still don't work

Comment: You're creating a promise for an array of promises - looks like you are missing a `Promise.all` call

Comment: What's wrong with using promises through the simpler `async`/`await` syntax?